# Using images and text from 19th century magazines

Tags: copyright

I'd like to use images and text from 19th century periodicals, magazinesand books on youtube and social media etc. They are sourced from Internet archive and smithsonian archive. I'm wondering are these magazines still in copyright or free to use for any purpose due to the year of first publication? All were published before 1923, mostly in the 1880s and 1890s